# Fading from one image to another with jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I can change picture by clicking or fade it to another by fadein or fadeout.
But i wanna load a loading.gif in between two pictures.

I have:

```
pic1.jpg
loading.gif
pic2.jpg
```

Which pic1 is default, And after 4 seconds, i wanna show the loading on pic1 and meanwhile load the pic2 and when pic2 loaded completely, the loading.gif disappears and pic1 fade into pic2.

Comment: <div id="pics">
  <img src="img/img1.jpg" id="pic1" />
  <img src="img/img2.jpg" id="pic2" />
  <img src="img/loadingpic.gif" id="loadingpic" />
</div>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pic1').fadeIn(500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
    $('#pic2').delay(4000).fadeIn(1500);
  });

</script>

Comment: It just swap from one image to another by an interval without showing loading in between.

Comment: See that now! Thanks for your response. Let me check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you wanna do like this?

```js
$(function () {
  flag = true;
  setInterval(function () {
    $("img").fadeOut(400, function () {
      $("img").attr("src", (flag) ? "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/1/" : "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/1/").delay(500).fadeIn(400);
      flag = !flag;
    });
  }, 2500);
});
```

```css
.img-holder {width: 400px; height: 200px; background: url("http://www.ajaxload.info/images/exemples/21.gif") center center no-repeat;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-holder">
  <img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/1/" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again. That's what i needed :)
Just one more thing. How can i stop it after loading the second picture? I just want it to fade from first pic to another and finish.

Comment: @user1767712 Just change the `setInterval` to `setTimeout`. Simple. `:)`

Comment: Appreciated dear Praveen Kumar :)